# Cohomology group induced by $d^*$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

It is well known that for a smooth manifold $M$, the de Rham cohomology group is defined by $$H_{dR}^k(M):=\frac{A^k(M)\cap \ker d}{A^k(M)\cap \text{im }d}.$$

Similarly, if we assume that $M$ being a compact smooth manifold, we can define a cohomology group by
$$
H_{d^*}^k(M):=\frac{A^k(M)\cap \ker d^*}{A^k(M)\cap \text{im }d^*},
$$
since we have $d^*\circ d^*=0$.

Then what properties do we have for this cohomology group? Is there an isomorphism between $H_{dR}^k(M)$ and $H_{d^*}^k(M)$?

Comment: What do you mean with $d^*$? Do you mean the compact de Rham cohomology? There's famous theorem known by Poincaré duality that relates the cohomology $H_c^k(M) \cong (H^{n-k}(M))^*$ where $H_c$ denotes the compact cohomology and $^*$ mens the dual vector space.

Comment: @user57, $d^*$ denotes the usual adjoint operator of $d$ in Hodge theory, such that $<d\alpha,\beta>=<\alpha,d^*\beta>$.  Compact cohomology means the de Rham cohomology of a compact manifold? Can you give a reference for the famous theorem you have mentioned above?

Comment: Oh ok thank you! Of course, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincaré_duality#Thom_isomorphism_formulation and Bott and tu's book also have a very good time with it.

Comment: @user57, thanks for the link of wiki, do you mean it is a result of Thom isomorphism? but I still do not think it is a kind of Thom isomorphism. By the way, what do you think of the answer by Three aggies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, $H^k_{d^*}(M) = H^k_{dR}(M)$. This holds for compact manifolds (with no boundary), since as mentioned in the post, the left is only well-defined on them.

This follows from the Hodge decomposition theorem, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_theory. In particular, it says that
$$
A^k(M) \cong \operatorname{im} d_{k-1} \oplus \operatorname{im} d^*_{k+1} \oplus {\mathcal H}^k,
$$
where ${\mathcal H}^k=\ker(dd^* + d^*d)$ is the space of harmonic forms. Harmonic forms are both closed and co-closed.

Then we see that
$$
H^k_{dR}(M) = \frac{\ker d_{k}}{\operatorname{im} d_{k-1}} = \frac{\operatorname{im} d_{k-1}\oplus {\mathcal H}^k}{\operatorname{im} d_{k-1}}={\mathcal H}^k.
$$

Similarly,
$$
H^k_{d^*}(M) = \frac{\ker d_{k}^*}{\operatorname{im} d_{k+1}^*} = \frac{\operatorname{im} d_{k+1}^*\oplus {\mathcal H}^k}{\operatorname{im} d_{k+1}^*}={\mathcal H}^k.
$$
Note here that no non-trivial element in $\operatorname{im} d_{k-1}$ can be $d^*$-closed, since $d^*(d\alpha)=0$ implies that $0=(d^*(d\alpha), \alpha)=\|d\alpha\|^2$.

Therefore, the two theories are the same.

Comment: Thanks, what a wonderful explanation! I think this is the answer I'm looking for.